# View trace route through interface

Tags: linux, firewall, traceroute

I would like to know if is possible to view the packet hops after a firewall through interface. Lets suppose that I have a firewall that block UPD or ICMP, so when I traceroute something I get this:

```
C:\Users\vide>tracert terra.com.br
Rastreando a rota para terra.com.br [208.84.244.116]
com no máximo 30 saltos:

  1    <1 ms    <1 ms    <1 ms  192.168.0.1
  2     3 ms     1 ms     1 ms  local switch
  3     1 ms     1 ms     1 ms  border router

  4     *        *        *     Esgotado o tempo limite do pedido.
  5     *        *        *     Esgotado o tempo limite do pedido.
  6     *        *        *     Esgotado o tempo limite do pedido.
  7     *        *        *     Esgotado o tempo limite do pedido.
  8     *        *        *     Esgotado o tempo limite do pedido.
  9     *        *        *     Esgotado o tempo limite do pedido.
 10     *        *        *     Esgotado o tempo limite do pedido.
 11   108 ms   108 ms   108 ms  www.terra.com.br [208.84.244.116]
```

There is a way to see each of theses * hops without changing any firewall rule in Linux without any tool?

Thanks in advanced

Answer (score 3):

No. Traceroute relies on ICMP Time Exceeded packets.